# Has the Sefer Abudraham been translated into English?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, jewish-books, english

I am looking for an English translation of David ben Josef ben David Abudirham's book on tefillah, entitled Abudraham.
Does one exist? If so where could I find it?

Comment: The Sefaria project is working on it, [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham), but the work is nowhere near complete, as far as I could tell. I don't know when they plan on finishing.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it does not exist

Comment: no. it would be a weird book to translate anyway, since half (maybe even more than half) of the text are quotations from Tanakh

Comment: @Matt Oh? .... "He certainly succeeded, as no one did before him, in writing a commentary which is very valuable, if not altogether indispensable, to the student, and which deserves to be translated and condensed for the benefit of those who still use the ancient ritual." ~ [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/690-abudarham-david-ben-joseph-ben-david)

Comment: @Shokhet that's a great find even if I disagree... Since I don't use translations though I guess it isn't right for me to judge what's worth translating or not.

Comment: I also [prefer using the original](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51293/shochtim-who-learned-from-translated-materials#comment135919_51293), @Matt :)

Comment: @Shokhet It doesn't look like they have any part of it translated (at least from skimming through the beginning). Was it removed, or did I look at the wrong part?

Comment: @Ploni You refer to the אבודרהם, right? (Not the שמלה חדשה?) ...I'm not sure what they have, but their plan is to get a crowd-sourced translation of all the important works of Judaica. I guess that means no one's been working on it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Shokhet I understood from your first comment that work had started on a translation of אבודרהם.

Comment: @Ploni Oh. I don't remember if I found any translated part; I left that comment a long time ago. I apologize for any confusion that may have caused; I don't know if Sefaria has any part of it translated. If you want to, you could start a translation, or [request one](http://www.sefaria.org/translation-requests).