# Shochtim who learned from translated materials

Tags: halacha, torah-study, translation, hechsher-certification, slaughter-shochet-shecht

The [Maharil](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%22%D7%9C) in his Tshusvos Chadashos ("New Responsa," mentioned [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%22%D7%9C#.D7.9B.D7.AA.D7.91.D7.99.D7.95)), writes (Siman 93) that the custom is not to give [kabblah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37705/5323) to *shochtim* who learned the laws shechita in German (translated materials).

Is this idea still practiced? Has a shochet been refused kabbalah because they learned the halachos in a different language, e.g. English?

Comment: I'll have to ask my rebbi about this one; I believe some of his students only use a translated, English שמלה חדשה, but I'm not certain of this. I personally prefer using the original whenever I learn something.

Comment: There is an English Simlah Chadasha?

Comment: Some things are very hard to learn in its original,like Emunos vdeaos

Comment: My rebbi has a translation; he turned down Artscroll's offer to publish it....he self-published it and gave out to the class; I also have the PDF. I have my own translation that I wrote, but I'm still proofreading it. If I'm right in my earlier assumption, they're using my rebbi's translation.

Comment: Interesting,he translated the Bechor as well?

Comment: No; his translation is pretty much word for word Simlah Chadasha, incorporating some of מטה אשר where necessary; his own הערות and such in footnotes.

Comment: The Simla Chadasha imposes some minimal level of learning.  Is the idea that the person COULDN'T learn in Hebrew, or it so happens that he DIDN'T learn in Hebrew?  The former might not qualify as learned enough (though nowadays, one who can only learn in English may have finished Shas, Chumash with Rashi and Ramban...)

Comment: I think it's more of ,not understanding the origins of the halacha

Comment: @shokhet any updates???

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Comment: @Shokhet - Would you be able to share the English version of Simla for me?

Comment: @sam rabbi Chaim Loike of the ou (also yu) published a translation

Comment: @user9841 see above comment, i would also like a copy of the pdf

Comment: @hazoriz It's on Google Books here: https://books.google.com/books?id=U_ImCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=chaim+loike&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAGoVChMIr_Haqcv-xgIVCqseCh3Mpgfs#v=onepage&q=chaim%20loike&f=false

Comment: @user9841 See above comment with link; yes, that is the book I was referring to

Answer (score 3):

There are many rabbonim who won’t give kabbala to a Shochet that doesn’t show a strong grasp of the Hebrew terms and precise language of the text in Hebrew. Potential Shochetim have failed tests because they answered all the questions in English, even though the answers were correct. I’ve been teaching shechita for years and this is my experience with the students I’ve sent to be tested. (There was even one Rav who only wanted to see the student read and explain a random Halacha in the Shulchan Aruch as his test.)

Comment: _meaning he needs to be able to learn inside, Gemara, Shulchan Aruch, etc._ source?

Comment: _The Shulchan Aruch says_ where?

Comment: I can’t find the source right now. I might have been mistaken as to it being from the Shulchan Aruch. I’ll try to find it and in the meanwhile I’ll edit my answer to exclude that part (as it wasn’t really a response to question asked, rather just to give  context to the prevailing custom today)

Comment: Adding sources for these practices (i.e. where did your Rabbeim get these practices from?) would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: The question was if there are rabbis today who won’t give kabala to someone who learned in English. Based on my experience the answer is yes, there are such rabbis. As to why they won’t, that’s not really the question, as the asker gave at least one reason himself in his question.

Comment: @mevaqesh source simla chadasha 1:6 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&pgnum=10 and shulchan Aruch HaRav 1:2 "ולכן כל רב שנותן קבלה לשוחט צריך לדרוש ולחקור עליו אם הוא אדם כשר ודרכיו מתוקנים ויראת ה' על פניוכד וגם שיהיה יודע ללמוד ולהבין בעצמו בגמרא ובפרש"י שאז יש לו לב להזהר  כמו שאמרו רז"ל אין בור ירא חטא ואיכא מאן דאמר בגמרא שאם קרא ושנה ולא שמש תלמידי חכמים דהיינו למוד הגמרא הרי זה בור וזהו דעת רב עמרם גאון הובא בב"י" https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/1/1/2/index.htm#_ftnref_29

Comment: who brings the Bais Yosef from ספר מחזיק הבדק ... ויש לנו להכותם ולהלקותם ולנדותם כל אותם השוחטים או הבודקים לעצמם עד שיקבלו עליהם שלא לעשות עוד עד שיהיו בקיאים בכ"ד ספרי הקדש ובתלמוד בכמה פרקים ויודעין... https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Yoreh_Deah.1.7.1